# Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in

Tags: php

I have this error coming up while importing products into opencart.

Can anyone suggest where the code needs correcting?

```
// Find the DIV tag with an id of "myId"
    foreach($html->find('div#accordion') as $e)
        return $e->innertext;
}
```

Comment: So what is $html? How are you creating the variable $html? What datatype is it?

Answer (score 0):

What the error means is that

> $html

Is not an object.

From the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) you can test for an object like this

```
if (!is_object($html)) {
    return false;
}else{
foreach($html->find('div#accordion') as $e){
return $e->innertext;
   }
}
```